# Meteor production getting fiber error

Tags: node.js, meteor

Meteor production getting the following error.Please Help me.With Node v0.12.1 and centos6.4.

```
/root/test/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:16
    throw new Error('`'+ modPath+ '.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibe
          ^
Error: `/root/test/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.28/fibers.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/test/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:16:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/test/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
error: Forever detected script exited with code
```

Comment: did you follow instructions for 'Running on own infrastructure' under the [deploy section of docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deploying)?  Specifically running `npm install` inside the "programs/server" directory of your built app.

Comment: we installed under the programs/server directory only.But getting same error.@user728291

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got that problem too, switch to node version 0.10.x, for me 0.10.36 solved it.