# meteor heroku application errors: cannot find module "fibers" even after specifying dependency

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor, node-modules, buildpack

I've sorted my way through all the buildpacks up to the latest updated https://github.com/kannans/heroku-buildpack-meteor recommended in this post: [Meteor Heroku App Crash after deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622156/meteor-heroku-app-crash-after-deployment), and no matter what happens, I end up getting an app crash after deployment stating that the node module "fibers" couldn't be found.

I also tried removing the heroku appdata and useri/heroku files, and loggin back into heroku. This solved another issue I was havng with node access in the appdata folder, but no this problem.

THEN, I used meteorhacks:npm to add the latest version of fibers right into package.json. It still can't find "fibers." I've worked on this for over 12 hours now, and no luck whatsoever.

Here's the heroku log:

```js
←[36m2015-10-13T06:50:22.294104+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v23 created by jbreasor@gmail.com
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:22.733668+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:27.944168+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .m
eteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.839825+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m module.js:340
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.839476+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.840133+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     throw err;
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.840141+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m           ^
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.842279+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.842281+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.842284+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.842283+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.842285+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at require (module.js:380:17)
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.842287+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/
server/boot.js:1:75)
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.842288+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.842290+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.842291+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.842292+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:29.842293+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:30.790398+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:30.791348+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:30.769943+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 8
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:35.579964+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .m
eteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
←[33m2015-10-13T06:50:38.096040+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
```

Comment: which node version do you use?

Comment: https://meteorhacks.com/how-meteor-uses-node: I'm trying to use this guide to retrieve my node version, but I'm not sure where this /.meteor file is. The one in my project has no such folders in it neither the .meteor in appdata. As far as the first approach is concerned, I can't use npm or sudo commands in my meteor project directory, although Meteor is automatically using node. I guess I'll keep trying to get the version for now.

Comment: the last build logs say node 4.1.2   but if my node was outdated, how would I fix it within meteor? I thought meteor automatically updated the version.

Comment: you should use 0.10.x version because there is no fiber package for higher node versions https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339852/meteor-production-getting-fiber-error/29341083#29341083

Comment: for heroku or meteor?

Comment: ok, i see now that heroku automatically uses node 4. version. How can I get the toolbelt to use a different node version? or should I change meteor's to update to the latest node instead?